# Django - {{ STATIC_URL }} error

Tags: django

I'm trying to add some features into my existing app called school.
At the moment I'm trying to add a picture into my template but all the template does it just display an empty box.

I'm reading Manging static file and I learn't how to display a picture hard coded but when I try to display a picture like this. It doesn't seem to work.

```
 <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/Crater.jpg" />
```

Here my setting : it was too long to post here

http://pastebin.com/ePw1h1aX

and my index.html template

```
 {% if students %}
 <ul>        
    {% for student in students %}    
<li><a href="{% url school:cat student.id %}">{{student.id}} {{student.First_name}}</li>    
{% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}

 <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/Crater.jpg" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)

//Or try in your template

{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/Crater.jpg' %}" />
```

Comment: I make a folder called staticfile? and put my images inside?

Comment: 1.I made a folder called staticfiles inside my school app. and I placed the picture inside and and I placed this inside my template  <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Crater.jpg" /> . It's not displaying the picture

Comment: I'll post a picture of my template

Comment: What os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'staticfiles'), does is . It's going to find a folder called staticfiles and when I insert this into my template  <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Crater.jpg" /> . I will display Crater.jpg?

Comment: have you tried {% load static %} then <img src="{% static 'images/crater.jpg' %}" />

Comment: I sent you the file and I just added {% load staticfiles %} , create another images folder and add <img src="{% static 'images/Crater.jpg' %}.

Comment: What happen was , the box disappear and when I right click to view source . <img src="/static/images/Crater.jpg

Comment: If your busy . You don't need to do it :]

Comment: Thank you very much . It also didn't work because I didn't close the <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Crater.jpg" bracket.

Comment: Do you know setting you fixed for me . Do you use them for production server or just local?

Comment: no, just only local. In production you just change the database, password, and username with the real one. But the format is both the same

Comment: Great , because it's easy to understand. Thank you cathy

Comment: Yeah, I just notice that you follow the setting I create, great :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look after is to make sure you have `{% load staticfiles %}` at the beginning of your template assuming you're using Django 1.4+ if you're using 1.3 it would be `{% load static %}` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the paths of your static files in your settings and the run "collect static files". Read carefully the documentation. Here is an extract of your settings file:

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
   # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
   # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this out .

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static_media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
    (r'^static_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'serve', {
        'document_root': '/your/static/folder/path/',
        'show_indexes': True }),)
```

And in template try like this

put your images in static direcory

And access like

```
  <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}your.jpeg">
```

I am just giving you and css example there you can try with images as well